# InsertAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity> when to use?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In LINQ to SQL, my understanding is that when I want to insert a collection of objects I am going to be using `InsertAllOnSubmit`. What I don't understand is when would I need to use `InsertAllOnSubmit<T>` as opposed to using just `InsertOnSubmit`?

What are the differences in either or with respect to the generic type parameter.

From LINQ definition,

```
public void InsertAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity>(IEnumerable<TSubEntity> entities)
   where TSubEntity : TEntity;
```

using like this:

```
db.SlickTableEntries.InsertAllOnSubmit<SlickTableEntry>(entries);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

vs. using it like this:

```
db.SlickTableEntries.InsertAllOnSubmit(entries);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

entries is a `List<SlickTableEntry>`.

How should I properly use this? Which version is better?

Comment: It is more convenient to use `InsertAllOnSubmit` when you have multiple entities already in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a convenience method that allows you to insert multiple entities in one call. This saves you the `foreach` loop. It does not change the way the database is accessed but it might be a little less CPU efficient according to the decompiled code (tiny effect).

The generic type parameter exists so that you can pass a derived type if your entities are in an inheritance relationship. Starting with C# covariance support this is no longer needed.

> Which one should be used in what situation?

If you have a list of entities use the list version. Otherwise, use the single item version. Do not specify the generic type argument. It is never required and just clutters the code.

There is no functional difference whatsoever. If it compiles it works. Just leave out the type argument and the compiler fills it in appropriately.